# Overlay one image with another in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to put one image and overlay it with the other one like in flag overlay apps. I want to make width and height of overlay image the same with the first image, scaling and fitting it with first image's dimensions. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Frame Layout.
Make the second image visible invisible programmatically as per your requirement. (image2.setVisiblity(View.GONE or View.VISIBLE))

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_flayout"    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView  
 android:id="@+id/image"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:src="@drawable/sketch" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<ImageView  
 android:id="@+id/image2"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_paren" 
 android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
 android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
 android:layout_alignBottomp="@id/image"
 android:visibility="INVISIBLE"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a relative layout with two imageview, by default they will overlap each other.
Now by using their ids you can control alpha or make it completely invisible

your layout should look something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width = "@dimen/required_width"
   android:layout_height = "@dimen/required_height">
   <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:src = "@drawable/your_image_one"/>
   <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:src = "@drawable/your_image_two"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in java code do this as per requirement:

```
ImageView imageview_one,imageview_two;
imageview_one = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
imageview_two = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
// to hide visibility of imageview_one
if(imageview_one.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
      imageview_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);//or View.INVISIBLE
      // making imageview2 visible
      imageview_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else
{
      imageview_two.setVisibility(View.GONE);//or View.INVISIBLE
      // making imageview1 visible
      imageview_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and to show a slight overlay you can control transparency of imageviews by using:

```
imageview_one.setAlpha(128); //for 50% transparency 0 for 100% transparent and 255 for 100% opaque
```

hope it helps... :)